# Lenses and Monomorphism Restriction

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have been working out on the examples given out in this [article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) for creating Lenses.

I created `Lens` as stated in the article and the following is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Lens

type Degrees = Double
type Latitude = Degrees
type Longitude = Degrees

data Meetup = Meetup { _name :: String, _location :: (Latitude, Longitude) }
makeLenses ''Meetup

meetupLat = location._1 :: Lens' Meetup Latitude
```

Now this code doesn't typecheck unless I include this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

But no where in the article, I could find out that they have mentioned
about the monomorphism restriction. So is this an normal thing or am I
doing something wrong here ?

Compiler used: GHC 7.6.2

Comment: What if you define it as `meetupLat :: Lens' Meetup Latitude`; `meetupLat = location._1`?

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks, that works without the extension. Can you post that as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a normal thing. The `lens` library relies heavily on polymorphism, so the monomorphism restriction (which makes things less polymorphic than they could be) doesn't interact so well with it. In your case, I think you could also write your code like this:

```
meetupLat :: Lens' Meetup Latitude
meetupLat = location._1
```

If you provide an explicit polymorphic type signature for a binding, the monomorphism restriction doesn't matter.

Note that `Lens' Meetup Latitude` is a *polymorphic* type, even though it looks monomorphic. The type variables are hidden inside the `Lens'` type synonym. In particular:

`Lens' Meetup Latitude` is [defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t%3aLens-39-) as `Lens Meetup Meetup Latitude Latitude`.

And `Lens Meetup Meetup Latitude Latitude` is [defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t%3aLens) as `forall f. Functor f => (Meetup -> f Meetup) -> Latitude -> f Latitude`

So this is all about the `f`. I think the monomorphism restriction would force a concrete instantiation of `f`, but you want to keep it polymorphic because different users of the lens will choose different `f`. For example [`view`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#v%3aview) will choose [`Const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Getter.html#t%3aConst) and [`set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#v%3aset) will choose [`Identity`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens/docs/Control-Lens-Setter.html#t%3aIdentity). So it is really important to keep the `f` polymorphic to allow the users of the lens these choices.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify the type on the function instead of on its definition

```
meetupLat :: Lens' Meetup Latitude
meetupLat = latitude._1
```

I believe this is because of the complicated type of `Lens'` behind the scenes means that while its definition has that type, the compiler still has a hard time guessing that `meetupLat` has the same type.  Maybe someone who has a deeper knowledge of the Monomorphism restriction can elaborate better.